# Как обратиться к соседском элементу через js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка

Хочу сделать раскрывающийся текст, при нажатии на "читать дальше"
Сделала так:

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.childNode[1].style.свойство
```

Мне кажется, что это, вроде как, должно работать, но не работает.
Пожалуйста, объясните почему..

Comment: `parentNode` - потому что он один. Но `childNodes` - `s`, их бывает больше одного.

Comment: всё равно не работает..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parentNode` - он всегда один, в единственном числе. Но `childNodes` - в множественном, их может быть больше одного.

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].style.display = "block";
```

Но у childNodes есть неприятный подвох. Он включает и пробелы (переносы строк) / тексты / комментарии между HTML-элементами:

```js
console.log( test.childNodes.length ); // 7! 

// пробел, <!--комментарий-->, пробел, <p>, пробел, <p>, пробел
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <!-- test -->
  <p>1<p>
  <p>1<p>
</div>
```

Поэтому надежнее использовать `children` - возвращающий список только из HTML-элементов.

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.children[1].style.display = "block";
```

Comment: а что значит children ?

Comment: @Дарья англ. - "Дети" ) Разница между ними только в том, что `childNodes` возвращает все дочерние узлы, а `children` - только HTML-элементы. На самом деле childNodes очень редко нужен: когда нужно достать именно какой-то внутренний текст / комментарий, который не обернут тегом.